# Get the window from a page

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to get a window from a page , so I've got a page frame in my window :

```
<Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Name="frmContent" Source="Page/Page1.xaml" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" Margin="0,0,0,0"  />
```

And trying to access my window from this page this way :

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Window1)this.Parent == null)
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("111");
    else
    wb1.ObjectForScripting = new MyScriptObject((Window1)this.Parent);
```

But the Parent returns null , so I see "111" message,

Where is my mistake and how to get window object correct ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The parent of the page will be the Frame, not the Window.

The easiest way is to use the [Window.GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow.aspx) static method:

```
var wnd = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

Comment: I get null using this solution:S

Comment: Works fine, child must be a xaml page loaded inside a frame that is inside a window, if those conditions are not met then there is no route to the window object thus null.

Comment: Is there a way to get the `Frame`?